# Find index of the maximum value in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array called `predictions` as follows

```
array([[3.7839172e-06, 8.0308418e-09, 2.2542761e-06, 5.9392878e-08,
        5.3137046e-07, 1.7033290e-05, 1.7738441e-07, 1.0742254e-03,
        1.8656212e-06, 9.9890006e-01]], dtype=float32)
```

In order to get the index of the maximum value in this array, I used the following

```
np.where(prediction==prediction.max())
```

But the result I am getting showing index 0 also.

```
(array([0], dtype=int64), array([9], dtype=int64))
```

Does anyone know why is it showing index 0 also?
Also how can I get just the index number instead of showing as (array([9], dtype=int64)

Comment: Is the 2d shape intentional?  You seem confused by corresponding 2 tuple `where` result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use built-in function for it:

```
prediction.argmax()
```

output:

```
9
```

Also, that index `0` is the row number, so the max is at row `0` and column `9`.

Comment: Okay perfect. Thanks. By the way how can I get just the index number instead of showing as `(array([0], dtype=int64), array([9], dtype=int64))` if I go for the `np.where(prediction==prediction.max())` way? I am just curious how to do it

Comment: @Anu you are welcome. I have to mentions that is a bad way to look for it since it has to loop array multiple times. But if you insist on it, simply `np.where(prediction==prediction.max())[1][0]`. Please feel free to accept answer to close the question. Thank you.

Comment: One more doubt: lets say if there are more than one elements in the array have same max val then what will this output? I tried some sample data and it is outputing the first index of the max value. Is it the right behaviour? I am doing a machine learning problem and if that is the case, it is just predicting that first index that has max value as the classified output

Comment: @Anu Your observation is correct. `argmax` returns the first max in the event of multiple max. Your approach `np.where(prediction==prediction.max())[1][0]`, however, should return all indices of max.

Answer (score 1):

The `predictions` array here is two dimensional. When you call `np.where` with only a condition, this is the same as calling `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()` which returns you the indices of the non-zero elements of `prediction==prediction.max()` which is a boolean array with the only non-zero element at `(0,9)`.

What you are looking for is the `argmax` function which will give you the index of the maximum value along an axis. You effectively only have one axis (2d but only one row) here so this should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers mentioned, you have a 2D array, so you end up with two indices. Since the array is just a row, the first index is always zero. You can bypass this in a number of ways:

1. Use [`prediction.argmax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html). The default `axis` argument is `None`, which means operate on a flattened array. Other options that will get you the same result are `prediction.argmax(-1)` (last axis) and `prediction.argmax(1)` (second axis). Keep in mind that you will only ever get the index of the *first* maximum this way. That's fine if you only ever expect to have one, or only need one.
2. Use [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) to get the linear indices similarly to the way you were doing:

   ```
   np.flatnonzero(perdiction == prediction.max())
   ```
3. Use [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) or [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), but extract the axis you care about:

   ```
   np.nonzero(prediction == prediction.max())[1]
   ```
4. [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) the array on input:

   ```
   np.where(prediction.ravel() == prediction.max())
   ```
5. Do the same thing, but with [`np.squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

   ```
   np.nonzero(prediction.squeeze() == prediction.max())
   ```